# Python PIL(Pillow) - How to get opacity on an image that appends into a PDF file?

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Goal: Get images onto a file (each image gets its own page). Each image will have text added onto it, and be able to be printed.

I have an array of images(png) that I am combining with an RGBA text image(a string of text pulled from an API), creating an alpha composite(combining them), and then appending to a PDF file. The issue is that The image can't be RGBA if I want to append it to the pdf, and making it RGB makes the background black instead of white/opaque.

Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import time



def write_custom_strings(model, strings, font_color):
  base = Image.open(f"./label_templates/{model}.png")
  # make a blank image for the text, initialized to transparent text color
  txt = Image.new('RGBA', base.size, (255,255,255,1))
  image_width = base.size[0]
  image_height = base.size[1]

  # get a drawing context
  d = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
  # Get font
  fnt = ImageFont.truetype('./cond_mono.ttf', 65)
  text_width, text_height = d.textsize(strings) 
  # draw text
  d.multiline_text(((image_width - text_width * 3.5)/2,725), strings, font=fnt, fill=font_color)
  out = Image.alpha_composite(base, txt)
  out = out.convert('RGB')
  out.show() # Show Image in development
  return out

def save_to_file(images):
  filename = generate_filename()
  if len(images) > 0:
    images[0].save(f"./product_labels/{filename}", save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])
  else:
    print("No new items")
def generate_filename():
  date = time.localtime()
   # Create filename using date/time
  return f"Custom-Orders:{str(date.tm_mon)}.{str(date.tm_mday)}.{str(date.tm_year)}-{str(date.tm_hour)}:{str(date.tm_min)}:{str(date.tm_sec)}.pdf"
```

Comment: I'd like to help but... your code is not runnable, you have removed the `import` statements, and it doesn't appear to write to a PDF which is the actual problem.

Comment: Why don't you just write the text on the image instead of writing it on a transparent background and compositing it?

Comment: If you're using ReportLab for PDF management, I recall you can get RGBA transparency by passing the same image as a mask image to the `drawImage` (or whatever it's called) call.

Comment: @MarkSetchell edited the code to include where I make the PDF. Not sure why I don't write the text directly, though it would still not allow me to append an RBGA image to a pdf.

Comment: @AKX I'll give ReportLab a try thanks

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you think you want something with transparency in your PDF. If you have a red image and you write on it in white, he image will remain red except where you write in white so why do you need transparency? A *"before"* and *"after"* image would help.

Comment: They're product labels so just incase one needs to be uniquely modified, it's nice to have them transparent to put into illustrator. Not an issue though, avoided it by just using white background on an RGB images. I also got rid of the composting and started writing directly on the image -- thanks for that.